# I have a script creating a google docs from a google sheet table. I want to keep all the script actions but make it save as pdf not as google docs

Tags: pdf, save-as

`

> function onOpen() {
> const Ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
> const menu = Ui.createMenu('AutoFill Docs');
> menu.addItem('Create New Docs','createNewGoogleDocs');
> menu.addToUi();
>
> }
>
> function createNewGoogleDocs() {
>
> const googleDocTemplate = DriveApp.getFileById('xxx');
> const destinationFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById('xxx');
> const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Customer PO');
> const rows = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
>
> rows.forEach(function(row, index) {
> if (index === 0) return;
> if (row[193]) return;
>
> const copy = googleDocTemplate.makeCopy(row[1], destinationFolder);
> const doc = DocumentApp.openById(copy.getId())
> const body = doc.getBody();
> //const friendlyDate = new Date(row[1]).toLocaleDateString();
>
> body.replaceText('{{1T}}', row[1]); //Title
> body.replaceText('{{2S}}', row[2]); //State
> body.replaceText('{{3C}}', row[3]); //Creator
> body.replaceText('{{4T}}', row[4]); //Ticaret Ünvanı
> body.replaceText('{{5F}}', row[5]); //Fatura Adresi
> body.replaceText('{{6T}}', row[6]); //Teslimat Adresi
> body.replaceText('{{7T}}', row[7]); //Telefon
> body.replaceText('{{8V}}', row[8]); //Vergi Dairesi
> body.replaceText('{{9V}}', row[9]); //Vergi Numarası
> body.replaceText('{{10T}}', row[10]); //Teslimat Tarihi
> body.replaceText('{{11T}}', row[11]); //Teslim Alacak Personel
> body.replaceText('{{12Ü}}', row[12]); //Ürün Adı_1
> body.replaceText('{{13Ü}}', row[13]); //Ürün Kapasitesi_1
> body.replaceText('{{14Ü}}', row[14]); //Ürün Valf Tipi_1
> body.replaceText('{{15T}}', row[15]); //Toplam Miktar_1
> body.replaceText('{{16D}}', row[16]); //Döviz Cinsi_1
> body.replaceText('{{17B}}', row[17]); //Birim Fiyat TL_1
> body.replaceText('{{18T}}', row[18]); //Toplam Tutar TL_1
> body.replaceText('{{19B}}', row[19]); //Birim Fiyat EUR_1
> body.replaceText('{{20T}}', row[20]); //Toplam Tutar EUR_1
> body.replaceText('{{21B}}', row[21]); //Birim Fiyat USD_1
> body.replaceText('{{22T}}', row[22]); //Toplam Tutar USD_1
> body.replaceText('{{23T}}', row[23]); //Tüp/Sepet Günlük kira TL_1
> body.replaceText('{{24T}}', row[24]); //Tüp/Sepet Günlük kira EUR_1
> body.replaceText('{{25T}}', row[25]); //Tüp/Sepet Günlük kira USD_1
> body.replaceText('{{26T}}', row[26]); //Teslimat ve Hizmet Bedeli TL_1
> body.replaceText('{{27T}}', row[27]); //Teslimat ve Hizmet Bedeli EUR_1
> body.replaceText('{{28T}}', row[28]); //Teslimat ve Hizmet Bedeli USD_1
> body.replaceText('{{29Ü}}', row[29]); //Ürün Adı_2
> body.replaceText('{{30Ü}}', row[30]); //Ürün Kapasitesi_2
> body.replaceText('{{31Ü}}', row[31]); //Ürün Valf Tipi_2
> body.replaceText('{{32T}}', row[32]); //Toplam Miktar_2
> body.replaceText('{{33D}}', row[33]); //Döviz Cinsi_2
> body.replaceText('{{34B}}', row[34]); //Birim Fiyat TL_2
> body.replaceText('{{35T}}', row[35]); //Toplam Tutar TL_2
> body.replaceText('{{36B}}', row[36]); //Birim Fiyat EUR_2
> body.replaceText('{{37T}}', row[37]); //Toplam Tutar EUR_2
> body.replaceText('{{38B}}', row[38]); //Birim Fiyat USD_2
> body.replaceText('{{39T}}', row[39]); //Toplam Tutar USD_2
> body.replaceText('{{40T}}', row[40]); //Tüp/Sepet Günlük kira TL_2
> body.replaceText('{{41T}}', row[41]); //Tüp/Sepet Günlük kira EUR_2
> body.replaceText('{{42T}}', row[42]); //Tüp/Sepet Günlük kira USD_2
> body.replaceText('{{43T}}', row[43]); //Teslimat ve Hizmet Bedeli TL_2
> body.replaceText('{{44T}}', row[44]); //Teslimat ve Hizmet Bedeli EUR_2
> body.replaceText('{{45T}}', row[45]); //Teslimat ve Hizmet Bedeli USD_2
> body.replaceText('{{46Ü}}', row[46]); //Ürün Adı_3
> body.replaceText('{{47Ü}}', row[47]); //Ürün Kapasitesi_3
> body.replaceText('{{48Ü}}', row[48]); //Ürün Valf Tipi_3
> body.replaceText('{{49T}}', row[49]); //Toplam Miktar_3
> body.replaceText('{{50D}}', row[50]); //Döviz Cinsi_3
> body.replaceText('{{51B}}', row[51]); //Birim Fiyat TL_3
> body.replaceText('{{52T}}', row[52]); //Toplam Tutar TL_3
> body.replaceText('{{53B}}', row[53]); //Birim Fiyat EUR_3
> body.replaceText('{{54T}}', row[54]); //Toplam Tutar EUR_3
> body.replaceText('{{55B}}', row[55]); //Birim Fiyat USD_3
> body.replaceText('{{56T}}', row[56]); //Toplam Tutar USD_3
> body.replaceText('{{57T}}', row[57]); //Tüp/Sepet Günlük kira TL_3
> body.replaceText('{{58T}}', row[58]); //Tüp/Sepet Günlük kira EUR_3
> body.replaceText('{{59T}}', row[59]); //Tüp/Sepet Günlük kira USD_3
> body.replaceText('{{60T}}', row[60]); //Teslimat ve Hizmet Bedeli TL_3
> body.replaceText('{{61T}}', row[61]); //Teslimat ve Hizmet Bedeli EUR_3
> body.replaceText('{{62T}}', row[62]); //Teslimat ve Hizmet Bedeli USD_3
> body.replaceText('{{63Ü}}', row[63]); //Ürün Adı_4
> body.replaceText('{{64Ü}}', row[64]); //Ürün Kapasitesi_4
> body.replaceText('{{65Ü}}', row[65]); //Ürün Valf Tipi_4
> body.replaceText('{{66T}}', row[66]); //Toplam Miktar_4
> body.replaceText('{{67D}}', row[67]); //Döviz Cinsi_4
> body.replaceText('{{68B}}', row[68]); //Birim Fiyat TL_4
> body.replaceText('{{69T}}', row[69]); //Toplam Tutar TL_4
> body.replaceText('{{70B}}', row[70]); //Birim Fiyat EUR_4
> body.replaceText('{{71T}}', row[71]); //Toplam Tutar EUR_4
> body.replaceText('{{72B}}', row[72]); //Birim Fiyat USD_4
> body.replaceText('{{73T}}', row[73]); //Toplam Tutar USD_4
> body.replaceText('{{74T}}', row[74]); //Tüp/Sepet Günlük kira TL_4
> body.replaceText('{{75T}}', row[75]); //Tüp/Sepet Günlük kira EUR_4
> body.replaceText('{{76T}}', row[76]); //Tüp/Sepet Günlük kira USD_4
> body.replaceText('{{77T}}', row[77]); //Teslimat ve Hizmet Bedeli TL_4
> body.replaceText('{{78T}}', row[78]); //Teslimat ve Hizmet Bedeli EUR_4
> body.replaceText('{{79T}}', row[79]); //Teslimat ve Hizmet Bedeli USD_4
> body.replaceText('{{80Ü}}', row[80]); //Ürün Adı_5
> body.replaceText('{{81Ü}}', row[81]); //Ürün Kapasitesi_5
> body.replaceText('{{82Ü}}', row[82]); //Ürün Valf Tipi_5
> body.replaceText('{{83T}}', row[83]); //Toplam Miktar_5
> body.replaceText('{{84D}}', row[84]); //Döviz Cinsi_5
> body.replaceText('{{85B}}', row[85]); //Birim Fiyat TL_5
> body.replaceText('{{86T}}', row[86]); //Toplam Tutar TL_5
> body.replaceText('{{87B}}', row[87]); //Birim Fiyat EUR_5
> body.replaceText('{{88T}}', row[88]); //Toplam Tutar EUR_5
> body.replaceText('{{89B}}', row[89]); //Birim Fiyat USD_5
> body.replaceText('{{90T}}', row[90]); //Toplam Tutar USD_5
> body.replaceText('{{91T}}', row[91]); //Tüp/Sepet Günlük kira TL_5
> body.replaceText('{{92T}}', row[92]); //Tüp/Sepet Günlük kira EUR_5
> body.replaceText('{{93T}}', row[93]); //Tüp/Sepet Günlük kira USD_5
> body.replaceText('{{94T}}', row[94]); //Teslimat ve Hizmet Bedeli TL_5
> body.replaceText('{{95T}}', row[95]); //Teslimat ve Hizmet Bedeli EUR_5
> body.replaceText('{{96T}}', row[96]); //Teslimat ve Hizmet Bedeli USD_5
> body.replaceText('{{97Ü}}', row[97]); //Ürün Adı_6
> body.replaceText('{{98Ü}}', row[98]); //Ürün Kapasitesi_6
> body.replaceText('{{99Ü}}', row[99]); //Ürün Valf Tipi_6
> body.replaceText('{{100T}}', row[100]); //Toplam Miktar_6
> body.replaceText('{{101D}}', row[101]); //Döviz Cinsi_6
> body.replaceText('{{102B}}', row[102]); //Birim Fiyat TL_6
> body.replaceText('{{103T}}', row[103]); //Toplam Tutar TL_6
> body.replaceText('{{104B}}', row[104]); //Birim Fiyat EUR_6
> body.replaceText('{{105T}}', row[105]); //Toplam Tutar EUR_6
> body.replaceText('{{106B}}', row[106]); //Birim Fiyat USD_6
> body.replaceText('{{107T}}', row[107]); //Toplam Tutar USD_6
> body.replaceText('{{108T}}', row[108]); //Tüp/Sepet Günlük kira TL_6
> body.replaceText('{{109T}}', row[109]); //Tüp/Sepet Günlük kira EUR_6
> body.replaceText('{{110T}}', row[110]); //Tüp/Sepet Günlük kira USD_6
> body.replaceText('{{111T}}', row[111]); //Teslimat ve Hizmet Bedeli TL_6
> body.replaceText('{{112T}}', row[112]); //Teslimat ve Hizmet Bedeli EUR_6
> body.replaceText('{{113T}}', row[113]); //Teslimat ve Hizmet Bedeli USD_6
> body.replaceText('{{114Ü}}', row[114]); //Ürün Adı_7
> body.replaceText('{{115Ü}}', row[115]); //Ürün Kapasitesi_7
> body.replaceText('{{116Ü}}', row[116]); //Ürün Valf Tipi_7
> body.replaceText('{{117T}}', row[117]); //Toplam Miktar_7
> body.replaceText('{{118D}}', row[118]); //Döviz Cinsi_7
> body.replaceText('{{119B}}', row[119]); //Birim Fiyat TL_7
> body.replaceText('{{120T}}', row[120]); //Toplam Tutar TL_7
> body.replaceText('{{121B}}', row[121]); //Birim Fiyat EUR_7
> body.replaceText('{{122T}}', row[122]); //Toplam Tutar EUR_7
> body.replaceText('{{123B}}', row[123]); //Birim Fiyat USD_7
> body.replaceText('{{124T}}', row[124]); //Toplam Tutar USD_7
> body.replaceText('{{125T}}', row[125]); //Tüp/Sepet Günlük kira TL_7
> body.replaceText('{{126T}}', row[126]); //Tüp/Sepet Günlük kira EUR_7
> body.replaceText('{{127T}}', row[127]); //Tüp/Sepet Günlük kira USD_7
> body.replaceText('{{128T}}', row[128]); //Teslimat ve Hizmet Bedeli TL_7
> body.replaceText('{{129T}}', row[129]); //Teslimat ve Hizmet Bedeli EUR_7
> body.replaceText('{{130T}}', row[130]); //Teslimat ve Hizmet Bedeli USD_7
> body.replaceText('{{131Ü}}', row[131]); //Ürün Adı_8
> body.replaceText('{{132Ü}}', row[132]); //Ürün Kapasitesi_8
> body.replaceText('{{133Ü}}', row[133]); //Ürün Valf Tipi_8
> body.replaceText('{{134T}}', row[134]); //Toplam Miktar_8
> body.replaceText('{{135D}}', row[135]); //Döviz Cinsi_8
> body.replaceText('{{136B}}', row[136]); //Birim Fiyat TL_8
> body.replaceText('{{137T}}', row[137]); //Toplam Tutar TL_8
> body.replaceText('{{138B}}', row[138]); //Birim Fiyat EUR_8
> body.replaceText('{{139T}}', row[139]); //Toplam Tutar EUR_8
> body.replaceText('{{140B}}', row[140]); //Birim Fiyat USD_8
> body.replaceText('{{141T}}', row[141]); //Toplam Tutar USD_8
> body.replaceText('{{142T}}', row[142]); //Tüp/Sepet Günlük kira TL_8
> body.replaceText('{{143T}}', row[143]); //Tüp/Sepet Günlük kira EUR_8
> body.replaceText('{{144T}}', row[144]); //Tüp/Sepet Günlük kira USD_8
> body.replaceText('{{145T}}', row[145]); //Teslimat ve Hizmet Bedeli TL_8
> body.replaceText('{{146T}}', row[146]); //Teslimat ve Hizmet Bedeli EUR_8
> body.replaceText('{{147T}}', row[147]); //Teslimat ve Hizmet Bedeli USD_8
> body.replaceText('{{148Ü}}', row[148]); //Ürün Adı_9
> body.replaceText('{{149Ü}}', row[149]); //Ürün Kapasitesi_9
> body.replaceText('{{150Ü}}', row[150]); //Ürün Valf Tipi_9
> body.replaceText('{{151T}}', row[151]); //Toplam Miktar_9
> body.replaceText('{{152D}}', row[152]); //Döviz Cinsi_9
> body.replaceText('{{153B}}', row[153]); //Birim Fiyat TL_9
> body.replaceText('{{154T}}', row[154]); //Toplam Tutar TL_9
> body.replaceText('{{155B}}', row[155]); //Birim Fiyat EUR_9
> body.replaceText('{{156T}}', row[156]); //Toplam Tutar EUR_9
> body.replaceText('{{157B}}', row[157]); //Birim Fiyat USD_9
> body.replaceText('{{158T}}', row[158]); //Toplam Tutar USD_9
> body.replaceText('{{159T}}', row[159]); //Tüp/Sepet Günlük kira TL_9
> body.replaceText('{{160T}}', row[160]); //Tüp/Sepet Günlük kira EUR_9
> body.replaceText('{{161T}}', row[161]); //Tüp/Sepet Günlük kira USD_9
> body.replaceText('{{162T}}', row[162]); //Teslimat ve Hizmet Bedeli TL_9
> body.replaceText('{{163T}}', row[163]); //Teslimat ve Hizmet Bedeli EUR_9
> body.replaceText('{{164T}}', row[164]); //Teslimat ve Hizmet Bedeli USD_9
> body.replaceText('{{165Ü}}', row[165]); //Ürün Adı_10
> body.replaceText('{{166Ü}}', row[166]); //Ürün Kapasitesi_10
> body.replaceText('{{167Ü}}', row[167]); //Ürün Valf Tipi_10
> body.replaceText('{{168T}}', row[168]); //Toplam Miktar_10
> body.replaceText('{{169D}}', row[169]); //Döviz Cinsi_10
> body.replaceText('{{170B}}', row[170]); //Birim Fiyat TL_10
> body.replaceText('{{171T}}', row[171]); //Toplam Tutar TL_10
> body.replaceText('{{172B}}', row[172]); //Birim Fiyat EUR_10
> body.replaceText('{{173T}}', row[173]); //Toplam Tutar EUR_10
> body.replaceText('{{174B}}', row[174]); //Birim Fiyat USD_10
> body.replaceText('{{175T}}', row[175]); //Toplam Tutar USD_10
> body.replaceText('{{176T}}', row[176]); //Tüp/Sepet Günlük kira TL_10
> body.replaceText('{{177T}}', row[177]); //Tüp/Sepet Günlük kira EUR_10
> body.replaceText('{{178T}}', row[178]); //Tüp/Sepet Günlük kira USD_10
> body.replaceText('{{179T}}', row[179]); //Teslimat ve Hizmet Bedeli TL_10
> body.replaceText('{{180T}}', row[180]); //Teslimat ve Hizmet Bedeli EUR_10
> body.replaceText('{{181T}}', row[181]); //Teslimat ve Hizmet Bedeli USD_10
> body.replaceText('{{182G}}', row[182]); //Genel Toplam Tutar TL
> body.replaceText('{{183G}}', row[183]); //Genel Toplam Tutar EUR
> body.replaceText('{{184G}}', row[184]); //Genel Toplam Tutar USD
> body.replaceText('{{185V}}', row[185]); //Vade / Gün
> body.replaceText('{{186T}}', row[186]); //Teslimat ve Hizmet Ücreti TL SİL?
> body.replaceText('{{187İ}}', row[187]); //İlgili ALTR Bölge Satış Müdürü
> body.replaceText('{{188D}}', row[188]); //DP No
> body.replaceText('{{189M}}', row[189]); //Müşteri Account no
> body.replaceText('{{190M}}', row[190]); //Müşteri SAP Kodu
> body.replaceText('{{191S}}', row[191]); //Sektör
> body.replaceText('{{192K}}', row[192]); //Kep Adresi
>
> doc.saveAndClose();
> const url = doc.getUrl();
> sheet.getRange(index + 1,194).setValue(url)
>
> })
>
> }
> `